# Redirect to electron app custom scheme with Google Identity Service

Tags: electron, google-drive-api, google-identity

I want to use the Google Drive API from an Electron application.

To authenticate, I use Google Identity Service. I took the example provided in the documentation here https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/js#step_1_set_up_the_sample which is essentially triggering the consent popup like this:

```
const tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    scope: SCOPES,
    callback: () => console.log('ok'),
});
tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: 'consent' });
```

It is meant to work in a web browser (and, indeed, it does work), but when running it in Electron, the consent popup display an error:

```
Error 400: invalid_request

If you’re the app developer, make sure that these request details comply with Google policies:

redirect_uri: storagerelay://file/?id=auth12850
```

Note: Using the Google Console, I have generated OAuth 2.0 Client IDs for a web app or for a desktop app and it does the same error.

Declaring `storagerelay://file/` as a redirect URL in the Google Console is not allowed.

The Google documentation https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#redirect-uri_custom-scheme seems to imply custom schemes are allowed for Android apps, iOS apps, and Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps but for regular desktop apps (like Electron app for example), apparently the only solution is to run a local web server and use `http://localhost:PORT` as redirect url.

Is there anyway to avoid running a local web server and just use a custom scheme?

Comment: Im running into the same issue in my project.. have you found a way to get it to work ?

Comment: @DRW Not for now, I think I will have to run a local http task.

Comment: From the research I have done since it is a desktop app we have to open an external browser to collect the login information and then pass that back to the electron app. this is the part that I am stuck on now atm .. but I am working on it .. let me know how you get along with the local http task and if it works or not maybe we can collectively solve this issue .

Comment: I use `node-static` in `main.ts` to serve on http://localhost:8888 a page from my app. It does the Google auth using `initTokenClient`. In the callback it passes the received token by redirecting to a custom scheme: ```location.href = `my-scheme://index.html?token=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(resp))}`;``` So the electron app receives the token and does `gapi.client.setToken(token)`. It works but it is not secured because anyone running an app on localhost:8888 can use my client_id (which is not secret) and pretend to be me, right? I think I will just host this page on a real server.

Comment: Yeah you don't want to reveal your client id like that. I myself am setting up the google auth on my asp.net core backend and serving it up to the frontend. It is the only option I have left to get this working .. good luck to you